# Understanding late firings

Tags: apache-beam

Given these examples:

1:

```
Window.<KV<String, DeviceData>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowSize())))
                .triggering(
                        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
                )
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(3))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes();
```

2:

```
           Window.<KV<String, DeviceData>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowSize())))
                .triggering(
                        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                                .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardHours(1))))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(6))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes();
```

Do I understand right, that

1. will trigger once after closing of the pane and then each time there is late data with max lateness of 3 hours?
2. will trigger when there is first data in the pane after 1 minute delay, once when the pane is closing and each time there is late data up to max 6 hours lateness?

Comment: Hi @Alex Tbk,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are used to determine when to emit the aggregated results of each window. Triggers allow Beam to emit early results and also process late data.`withAllowedLateness()` you can process the data which is late. If withAllowedLateness is set then the default trigger will emit new results immediately whenever late data arrives. As mentioned in this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html),

> Override the amount of lateness allowed for data elements in the
> output PCollection and downstream PCollections until explicitly set
> again. Any elements that arrive are later than this as decided by the
> system-maintained watermark will be dropped. The value in this also
> determines how long the state will be kept around for old windows and
> once no elements will be added to a window (because this duration has
> passed) any state associated with the window will be cleaned up.

For example,

```
PCollection<String> items = ...;
 PCollection<String> windowed_items = items.apply(
   Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
      .triggering(
          AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
              .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime
                  .pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardHours(1))))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(1)));
 PCollection<KV<String, Long>> windowed_counts = windowed_items.apply(
   Count.<String>perElement());
```

In the above code,  if you want  to emit the values which were available when the watermark has passed the end of the window, and  then outputs the data that arrive late once-per  hour until we have finished processing the next 24-hours of data.

Comment: You just repeated my question

Comment: Hi @AlexTbk, Can you clarify your requirement more?

Comment: The two questions are clearly stated in the initial posting